# GWT RequestFactory with Command pattern

Tags: gwt, command-pattern, requestfactory

Are you currently using the Command Pattern in combination with RequestFactory? I'd like to use it but since RequestFactory doesn't allow inheritance, I'm not sure how to do it.

If anyone has been through this issue and found a way to implement it, I'd be glad to know.

Thank you!

Comment: anyone? any hints/ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: GWT-Platform has build-in command pattern to handle RPC.

Comment: GWT 2.4 fixes a couple of interesting issues that may lead to this possibility, but I'm not certain:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5367 
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6234

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that I can explain it right but I think that you try to mix oranges and apples.

RequestFactory framework is a very smart thing and it does a lot of things well and clever BUT you got to embrace the way of thinking and design it offers. Learn it and you will pleased by results. It seems like a complex concept but it worth it. Do not fight to fit it in to the box of "Command Pattern". As you give little information on what you try to achieve I can not give you a HowTo for your case. Sorry.

Ask some more concrete question and I am sure you will get an answer on StackOverflow.

Good Luck!